# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to use Django's built in test module with no luck

I've tried changing my database, running it locally, etc and keep getting hit with the same error:

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'error' at line 1")

test.py module below

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from universal.models import *
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your tests here.
class UPCImageSearchTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setup(self):
        self.url = reverse('UPCImageSearch')
        testUpc = Item.object.create(item_upc = '001100110011')
        print(self.url)

    def test_fetch_success(self):
        self.data = {
        'upc':''
        }

    response = self.client.get(self.url,self.data)
    self.assertEqual(200,response_status_code)

    def test_fetch_failed(self):
        self.data = {
            'upc':''
        }

    response = self.client.get(self.url,self.data)
    self.assertEqual(500,response_status_code)
```

Comment: As posted, the `response = self.client(...)` and `self.assertEqual()` lines are outside of the functions, therefore the reference to `self` should be causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out what the main issue was. It was a migration failure in django. After fixing it, it started actually working

Comment: Maybe you can add some detail and mark it as answered so that it would help others.